# How to get one single record from spring backend and display it on angular frontend

Tags: angular, spring, frontend, spring-webflux

I have one microservice on spring webflux backend and I am developing the UI for the same service. Now I have a GET request which return member details on the basis on memberId provided.How to get member details from backend and display it in frontend. GET request looks like this: localhost:8081/viewbill/234.
I tried implementing it in angular but didnt find any success. I am not getting how to display the data on Angular UI.I have also attached the postman screenshot for the GET endpoint.
Here is my Angular file structure:[image: Postman ss]

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'get-member', component:MemberListComponent},
  {path:'view-member', component:MemberDetailsComponent}
];
```

member-service.ts

```
 viewMemberDetails(memberId:string):Observable<any>
  {
    const url="http://localhost:8081/viewbill/"+memberId;
    return this.httpclient.get<any>(url);
    
  }
}
```

member-details.component.ts

```
export class MemberDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  member:Member=new Member();
  memberId:any;

  constructor(private memService:MemberService,private route:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.memService.viewMemberDetails(this.memberId).subscribe(data=>{
        this.member=data;
        console.log(data);
        
      });
  }
```

member-details.component.html

```
 <div class="container">
        <h2>Member Details</h2>
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>MemberId</th>
              <th>FirstName</th>
              <th>LastName</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              </tr>
              <tr *ngFor=let m of member>
              <th>{{m.memberId}}</th>
              <th>{{m.firstName}}</th>
              <th>{{m.lastName}}</th>
              <th>{{m.age}}</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          
        </table>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
<router-outlet></router-outlet
```

I tried displaying the data using ngfor but got error Type 'Member' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable | null | undefined'.

```
      <tr *ngFor="let m of member">
```

Comment: post the result of the `console.log(data);`

Comment: I am getting null in console

Comment: try `console.log(data.data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by the `memberId` you are using, there is any data at all to get (which might be the simple reason you are getting a `null`, and that you are using a `memberId` at all, because in the example you provided `memberId` is never initialized.

Firstly as @Aid Hadzic mentioned, `*ngFor` requires an Interable to iterate over its intividual values. The variable `member` you provide is of type `Member` which is propably not iterable.
Something like

```
<tr *ngIf="!!member">
      <th>{{member.memberId}}</th>
      <th>{{member.firstName}}</th>
      <th>{{member.lastName}}</th>
      <th>{{member.age}}</th>
</tr>
```

is closer to what you want.

Secondly I would highly recommend you to keep you application as reactive as possible. Meaning you might want to avoid manual value handling and updating and make use of best practises like the `async`-Pipe in this case which is natively provided by Angular. This would mean that in your case a setup like the following might be worth a look:

```
export class MemberDetailsComponent {
  
  memberId:any; 
  // this seems to be undefined maybe try a static value for your tests here first,
  // for example the Id from your postman Call `568Shri`
  

  member$:Observable<Members>=this.memService.viewMemberDetails(this.memberId);
  
  constructor(private memberService:MemberService) { }
}
```

```html
<tr *ngIf="(member$ | async) as member">
      <th>{{member.memberId}}</th>
      <th>{{member.firstName}}</th>
      <th>{{member.lastName}}</th>
      <th>{{member.age}}</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi Chund thanks for the answer the first method worked for me. Second one is causing erros as of now. Can you please guide me on what the line *ngIf=!!member does? I also initialised memberID as you said with default value and it worked

Comment: Hi @Abhi06 . Of course. *ngIf is a structural directice that lets you decide whether a given block of html-code is to be included in the DOM or not and expects a value that can be evaluated as either 'truthy' and 'falsy'. For example an Object is 'truthy', while null and undefined are 'falsy'. The "!!" in front of "members" does nothing but negating the truthvalue of "members" twice ==> If members is an object !!members evaluates to "true" and the <tr> block is rendered, otherwise it isn't. If this helps don't forget to rate the answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply. It helped alot. As for the rating I am new and dont have sufficient reputation to cast vote :(

Comment: heyho, no probs. I edited my answers since there were syntax errors in the ngIf-Directive. Maybe this helps